# Command not found: django-admin.py

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am a complete beginner to Python/Django, but I want to dive right in and start experimenting. Thus I was following this guide on installing Python/Django http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django.

Everything is working fine until the step

`django-admin.py startproject hellodjango`

Where I get

`command not found: django-admin.py`

Now I have tried a few things, but none have really worked out. Is there someone kind enough to point me in the right direction?

P.S. Is there a great guide out there on running Python/Django locally on a Mac to run and test apps?

I'm on Mac OS X Lion, Python 2.7.

Comment: You need to give more details. What have you tried? It sounds like django isn't installed or not on your python path. You should look into running your django apps with virtualenv which will give you an encapsulated enviroment in which to install django etc.

Comment: @pastylegs: That guide does suggest using virtualenv.

Comment: Have you tried the official [Django tutorial guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/install/)?

Comment: @pastylegs yes, the guide suggests using virtualenv, up to that step I had no problems. However I acknowledge the fact that I may be missing something really basic here (the guide was followed very closely though).

Comment: Looks like I had to reinstall Django on a global basis to make this work.

Comment: You shouldn't need to install Django globally. If you needed to do that to make it work, your virtualenv wasn't set up correctly.

Comment: This could be caused by your installation getting interrupted the first time.  So any reinstall may fix the problem.

Answer (score 77):

When that didn't work for me, I tried `python -m django startproject mysite` and it worked.

Answer (score 40):

Actually, if you use Ubuntu, it's just `django-admin` not `django-admin.py`.

Resides in `/usr/bin` 
Probably the same thing on Mac.
You're using a Windows tutorial.

It may also tell you

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and that is actually

```
python ./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: had the same problem on Debian 9. This fixed it for me, too.

Comment: django-admin worked for me

Answer (score 24):

I tried as the method, it worked.

```
pip uninstall django
sudo pip install django
django-admin startproject example
```

It worked well.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you properly did the `source bin/activate` command. If you skip that, or do it in a different terminal window, or close the window then re-open it, you won't be in the virtualenv and you won't have access to the `django-admin.py` command in your environment.

Comment: Actually I think that worked out alright. I didn't get any errors up to that point. I think I also successfully am in virtualenv: `(project)➜  loc  django-admin.py startproject project`

Answer (score 13):

If you´re on Windows, here´s what worked for me (using pylauncher):

```
$ py -m django startproject myproject
```

Answer (score 8):

To solve this problem, you need:

1. Find the main folder of Django, and find the `django-admin.py` file

   Typically, the file is in `<YOUR_DJANGO_FOLDER>/bin/django-admin.py`
2. Create a link for this file

   ln -s /bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin
3. Type `django-admin` in your command to check if it works

Answer (score 5):

**To Windows users**

using `django-admin` instead of `django-admin.py` worked for me in Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For me this one worked

```
python3 -m django startproject mysite
```

Then it doesn't tell you that it created file you must check by yourself in your home

```
hardrive/user/urhome
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't create it in your home directory so just use your computer file manager search and search for "mysite"

Answer (score 4):

As Timmy said above, it could just be that django-admin.py is not on your system path.
See here - https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/InstallationPitfalls - for 3 possible causes with solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I have used follwong command to install (/usr/local/bin) MAC OS

```
pip install django

django-admin startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 4):

```
python3 -m django startproject mango
```

Answer (score 2):

The following guide in official site https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/InstallationPitfalls

First, you should find location of `django-admin.py` by

```
which django-admin.py
```

Example: in my case

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py

You use `sudo ln -s` to relocate `django-admin-py` to `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

after that change permission of the django-admin to be executable
`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py`

Now you can use
`django-admin.py startproject mysite` 
to create your django project

---

If you want to change `django-admin.py` to `django-admin` to look like more compact you can use
`sudo mv /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin`

Hope this help for you !

Answer (score 2):

This simply worked for me.
Install django on your virtualenv:

```
pip install django
```

And then run:

```
django-admin startproject myprojectname
```

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same problem, I just did an upgrade and that's it, it worked, I hope this is useful for future problems in Linux:

```sh
pip install --upgrade django
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be a chance that your path is not correct. Ubuntu has a .local/bin folder which pip uses to install module binaries and you need it in your path to use django or any shell commands installed using pip.

- Open `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`
- Add the following line and save it

```
export PATH="/home/animesh/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

- restart the shell with `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

To windows users out there: I have faced this problem several times and here are the checkpoints:

When there is problem initiating a new project, make sure:

1)  python is working in the command line (type in python and see if you get the console)

2)  specify the full path of django-admin.py in the command

3)  check django-admin.py is in the system path

4)  cd the command line path to where you want the new project

Screenshot of what finally worked for me (only the last command):
https://flic.kr/p/r9LJ67
(stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post pictures yet)

Answer (score 1):

If you come across `command not found: django-admin.py` problem which means  you don't installed django frame work. You should install the framework using pip.

```
pip install django
```

After that look at the directory if the related script exist or not.
Look into `C:\Python27\Scripts`folder to check for django-admin.py exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

if you install django by pip

- ensure you have installed django:

> pip list  or pip freeze

if there is django
then

- get location of django:

> pip show django

if location is '/Users/xxxxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages' then

- relocate django-admin-py to /usr/local/bin:

> ln -s /Users/xxxxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py

Answer (score 1):

Get site-package path with Python:

```
import site; site.getsitepackages()
```

And run django-admin.py directly:

```
python (your-site-package-addresss)/django/bin/django-admin.py startproject hellodjango
```

On Mac: If this works you can go and add django-admin.py to your path using symlink:

```
sudo ln -s (your-site-package-addresss)/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin
```

(could be that you have to reopen terminal or reinstall django to get the symlink working)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my complete python path to desktop and tried and it's working well for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case i simply forgot to run `pip install django`

Answer (score 0):

On `RHEL` stock python config:

`django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running macOS and I'm using pyenv instead of virtualenv. I'm not sure if they behave similarly, but I was having the same problem in which django-admin.py was not found.

After a while I've noticed that I had a warning after installing django:
`pyenv: cannot rehash: /Users/msvolenski/.pyenv/shims/.pyenv-shim exists`

Once I **deleted** this file and ran `pyenv rehash` it all started working perfectly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Users first search for django-admin, right click on the file that has been found and open file location and keep it open.

Using Windows Powershell, cd into the the folder where you want to create your django project

when your in the right folder write the full path of where django-admin is located in my case I am using Anaconda 3 so the file location is

C:\Users\Sen\Anaconda3\Scripts

so in Windows PowerShell type C:\Users\Sen\Anaconda3\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject [name of project]

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when migrating to AWS Beanstalk it was installed and everything but i noticed the alias was not working but when i called the entire thing path and all it worked so i just rebooted the boxes and it worked i think the alias list is not updated automatically after you install.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the PATH:

Put this in the .bash_profiel and the source it (for mac users only):
(change the location with the location of your installed python libraries)

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same problem, and is on MacOs, here is what I did, and it worked for me:

If you've installed python directly from the official website, uninstall it, and install it once again using brew:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

$ brew install python3
```

This will also install the pip3 for you, so you don't have to install it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

The issue resolved after I upgraded the django version using

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

Then run

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There was a space in one of the names in the path to my project. I set up a new virtual environment in a new directory and did all the same things and it works.

Sometimes it is the simple things...

Comment: The toolchain is generally able to cope with spaces in file names just fine. Probably you have a quoting error somewhere in your shell configuration files or something.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just starting out. It is very important to adopt best practices. You will face many dependency related issues with this approach of development. In this case it is always recommended to work with a virtual environment for each python project.

This will ensure fresh installation of project-specific dependencies that do not overlap with what the system you are running on already has.

If you have not already noticed, you will come across more issues such as python3 not working with earlier versions of django. pip will skip install as it checks and finds a version of django already installed. So this cannot be stressed enough, always use a virtual environment for local setups.

to do so:

1. cd [your project path]

virtualenv venv

2. you can active your environment by :

source ./venv/bin/active

3. install your requirements packages with pip :

pip install -r 
or pip install 
you can also install your requirements modules without activate the environment

./venv/bin/pip install

4. to run your python script use :

python <.py file>

and if you didn't activate your env use :

./venv/bin/python <.py file>

Answer (score -1):

I take as reference this page and it tells you what to do very clearly.

https://realpython.com/django-setup/

Here are the steps in short if you don't want to visit the site.

1. Set up a virtual environment in a folder that you created. I created in Desktop a folder named "python_project". Inside that folder run:  **python3 -m venv env** in terminal.
2. Then activate the virtual environment with command: **source env/bin/activate**
3. Install django after activating virtual environment with this command: **python -m pip install django**
4. Pin your dependencies to make sure that you’re keeping track of which Django version you installed: **python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt**
5. Start a django project **django-admin startproject**
6. Then start a django app which should be inside first folder of the project so first change directory to  then in terminal enter this command: **python manage.py startapp**

Then most probably you will see a scaffolding like this:

```js
setup/
│
├── example/
│   │
│   ├── migrations/
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   │
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
│
├── setup/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
│
└── manage.py
```