# Django-admin.py is not working....it says command not found

Tags: python, django-admin

i am using django 1.9.7 and python 2.7.12 and have all the packages installed for django and python using pip install django and pip install virtualenv. Even if i do pip freeze it gives me the list of these things installed but if i execute django-admin.py it says command not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu use `django-admin` not `django-admin.py`

[Command not found: django-admin.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250086/command-not-found-django-admin-py)