# I can't create new project with bitnami django on Linux

Tags: python, django, bitnami

i just install Django Stack 2.1.5-0, and i want to create new project with this command:

> sudo django-admin.py startproject coba

but the terminal give me result:

> bash: django-admin command not found

and i want to create it in here:

> opt>djangostack>apps

do i need to install python3 and django first event though i have use django stack?

please help me :)

Comment: You need to create virtual environment then activate it then install django then run the command. Better you find some better tutorials for basic django, and also you can try django official documentation `poll` project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command not found: django-admin.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250086/command-not-found-django-admin-py)

Comment: You shouldn't be using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here. Our stacks include all the necessary components to run your applications and runs independently of your system's packages. In your case, in order to start using the packages of the Bitnami installation, you will need to load the Bitnami Environment. You only need to execute this command:

```
cd /opt/djangostack
sudo ./use_djangostack
```

> Note: I used /opt/djangostack as installdir based on the information you gave. If you are using a different installation path, just use that directory.

You will learn more about the Bitnami Console here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/how-to/understand-bnconsole/