# Django for Mongodb can't find django-admin.py

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework

I am starting to learn to use **MongoDB** with **Django**, so I followed [this tutorial](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html#configuration) to start up.

I created my virtual environment using `python3.6 -m venv MongodbTestVenv`, and activated it using `source MongodbTestVenv/bin/activate`. Everything worked fine, so far.

I installed **Django-nonrel** using `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5`.

I installed **djangotoolbox** using `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox`.

I installed **Mongo DB engine** using `pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine`.

I checked with `pip list` to ensure everything is installed:

```
(MongodbTestVenv) MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:MongodbTestProject hugovillalobos$ pip list
Package               Version
--------------------- -------
Django                1.5.11 
django-mongodb-engine 0.6.0  
djangorestframework   3.9.2  
djangotoolbox         1.8.0  
pip                   19.0.3 
pymongo               3.7.2  
setuptools            28.8.0
```

But, when I type `django-admin startproject MongodbTest`, I get this error: `-bash: django-admin: command not found`.

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250086/command-not-found-django-admin-py/52134281), but all answer are related to the location of **django-admin.py** file, so I found it using `which django-admin.py`, and this is the result:

```
(MongodbTestVenv) MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:MongodbTestProject hugovillalobos$ which django-admin.py
/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/MongodbTestProject/MongodbTestVenv/bin/django-admin.py
```

I can see that the file is located on the active virtual environment directory, so I can't understand why it can't be located.

I don't know what I am missing, I have never had problems with **Django** when using relational database and I install regular **Django** versions using just `pip install Django`.

Comment: Because the file is called `django-admin.py`, not `django-admin`. But *all* of these projects are hopelessly out of date and unsupported. You shouldn't be using them. I doubt any of them will even work with Python 3.6. If you want to use MongoDB with Django, have a look at Djongo.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel Roseman. I checked Djongo and it was as natural to Django as any other I tried before

Answer (score 0):

You say you ran:

```
django-admin startproject MongodbTest
```

but your bash is able to find `django-admin.py` from that `which` statement.

Try what your bash knows:

```
django-admin.py startproject MongodbTest
```