# getting trouble in django-admin setup

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-admin-filters

PS C:\Users\laveen\pycharmprojects\DjangoCourse> django-admin
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- django-admin
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: are you using virtualenv? if yes, try `venv\Scripts\django-admin <command here>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command not found: django-admin.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250086/command-not-found-django-admin-py)